# Exporting Transparent Background from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, transparency-opacity

I have QGIS version 3.4.3 which does not have print composer.  I have a series of lines/tracks/boundaries, etc that are in a layer.  I am trying to export that layer with a transparent background for installation in a Garmin GPS unit.  I have successfully completed all steps with the exception of creating the transparent background.

I have scoured the web, looked through the technique in Print Composer which is not available in this version and tried to no avail at GPS File Depot.

What am I overlooking?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Qgis 3.4 has print composer, but it's been renamed as "print layouts".

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  This solved the transparency issue for printing, but still didn't get me to the overlay part.  I ended up brute forcing it track by track and converting them using Javawa.  Thank you again when I have more time I will try to get this to work via QGIS